# How to redefine separation procedure to get 0-1 knapsack with odd number of items

Tags: knapsack, cutting-planes

So I have a 0-1 knapsack problem:

\begin{align}\max&\quad \sum_j c_j x_j\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad \sum_j a_j x_j \leq b\\
&\quad x_j \in \{0,1\}\end{align}

but it has an additional requirement that the number of items in an optimal knapsack should be ***odd***. I know I can model it with one extra variable, but the assignment calls for *redefining separation procedure*.

To my understanding, that means writing a callback procedure that will generate additional constraints in branch-and-cut algorithm. I know that 0-1 knapsacks have special kinds of inequalities to strengthen LP formulation, but I don't know how to incorporate them with the requirement of odd number of items.

Comment: Cross-posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339581/separation-problem-for-0-1-knapsack-with-odd-number-of-items

Comment: The phrase "redefining the separation procedure" might not imply new cuts. It might refer to changing how a node is split into child nodes.

Comment: @prubin The whole phrase is "use default branching
rule and redefine separation procedure", so I thought it was to do with new cuts

Comment: Yes, I would agree given the full phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I also do not know how to embed 0-1-knapsack specific inequalities with the odd number solution requirement. However, I know how to generate cuts that will reduce the search space whenever an even number of items is picked. So, let $x^{*} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an optimal, eventually fractional, solution. If $\sum_{j} x^{*}_j$ is an integer even number, then we can say that $\sum_{j \in I} x_j - \sum_{k \notin I} x_k \leqslant |I| - 1$, where $I = \{j : x^*_j > 0\}$. With these thoughts in mind, fluidly we design the below separation algorithm (callback):

1. Get $x^{*}$ and $I$.
2. If $\sum_{j} x_j^{*}$ is integer and even then:
3. Add $\sum_{j \in I} x_j - \sum_{k \notin I} x_k \leqslant |I| - 1$ to the formulation.

Actually, we can play a little bit with the addition of a new variable; as you commented earlier. Let $y \in \mathbb{N}$ be a natural variable, then we can force the formulation, on its integer solution space, to consider only $\sum_{j} x_j$ as odd numbers, if we say that $\sum_{j} x_j = 2 y + 1$.

Furthermore, we can try out new branching rules, where we basically branch on odd numbers.

1. Get $x^{*}$
2. Let $F = \lfloor \frac{\sum_{j} x^*_j}{2} \rfloor$, and $C = \lceil \frac{\sum_{j} x^*_j}{2} \rceil$
3. If $C = F$ then:
4. start *branching* on $x_j$
5. **exit**
6. If $F$ is odd then:
7. *branch* on $\sum_{j} x_j \leqslant F$
8. *branch* on $\sum_{j} x_j \geqslant C + 1$
9. else:
10. *branch* on $\sum_{j} x_j \leqslant F - 1$
11. *branch* on $\sum_{j} x_j \geqslant C$

Case anyone has any questions or suggestions, please feel free.

UPDATE 1: Updating step 3 of the first algorithm. ps.: thanks @RobPratt for the observation and the edge case.

Comment: Your no-good cut is too strong. For example, it prevents setting $x_i=1$ for all $i\in I$ and $x_j=1$ for exactly one $j\notin I$. You can repair this approach by using the more general *canonical* no-good cut.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If you are talking about the step "3. Add $\sum_{j \in I} x_j \leqslant |I| - 1$ to the formulation", it is not clear for me why it prevents setting $x_j = 1$ for exactly one $j \notin J$. Can you elaborate a little bit this?

Comment: Suppose $I=\{1,2\}$. Your cut forbids $x_j=\{1,2,3\}$, which should instead be allowed.

Comment: Oh! Now I see your point, thanks for the feedback. I have updated the answer, now I think the new inequality suits this case.